# in Jboss 7 ERROR org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor [process] Error processing request: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: jboss7.x

Jboss is hanging behind apache httpd. AJP threads are hanging which causes the following error:

```
org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor [process] Error processing request:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

We took thread dump and observed that 243 threads were observed and 223 were in a runnable state while 20 were in a waiting state.

How can I terminate those threads after the task has finished?

We tried with

```
<connector name="ajp" protocol="AJP/1.3" scheme="http" socket-binding="ajp" keepalive-time="300000"/>.
```

However with this entry we are getting an exception when parsing the xml. The server is not getting started; however by reverting those changes
Jboss starts normally.

Comment: What is the current heap size set in jboss, is it sufficient for your app? The keepalive-time="300000" is quite high, change it to keepalive-time="100" or keepalive-time="10".